# How to describe the physics process of scintillation?

Tags: optics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, x-rays, particle-detectors

I want to find some references on describing the physics of scintillation. As we know the lights generated by scintillator through atom activation and de-activation, and each material has a
spectrum and its intensity veries with wave length as shown in the figure below. How to calculate the number of lights generated by the scintillator materials and their distribution? Can we get the light emission spectrum in the figure below from theory?
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillation_(physics)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate scintillation yield of materials is impractical. It's determined experimentally.

The power of mathematics in physics blinds many to its severe weaknesses. While it may be insightful, even very simple problems are often very difficult to compute. Of course, textbooks avoid these problems, thus perpetuating the illusion.

Comment: While I appreciate and support the basic message, it is misleading in this particular context - there do exist rather accurate models that allow the calculation of scintillating yields from a mix of first principles and basic measurements. (Of course  these are far from being analytical)

Comment: @rfl Can you cite any papers on this? A search of "CsI scintillation yield" yields many experimental papers.

Comment: See e.g. https://nest.physics.ucdavis.edu/ for xenon. We can argue about what constitutes first principles and what doesn't.  But the question is too vague to know what you're actually looking for...

Comment: @rfl I suspect Xe is simpler than CsI(Tl). And I'm not looking for anything, but the OP mentioned CsI.